# Как правильно помечать костыли в коде?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Зачастую при любой разработке возникает необходимость написать код, про который известно заранее что он:

1. Крайне не гибок.  Или..
2. Может вызвать баги, проблемы в дальнейшем. Или..
3. Совершенно не читаем.

Или такой код достаётся по наследству, и хочется пометить места, которые надо затем выправить. Такой код называется по-русски **костыль**. К сожалению на англоязычных сайтах трудно найти информацию об этом, так как у них термин "костыль" - отсутствует в принципе. Рекомендуют переводить, как "kludge" - но это не часто понимают.

**Вопрос** - как помечать костыли в коде комментариями, чтобы было просто составить список из всех костылей в проекте, и крайне желательно - чтобы была их обозримость в IDE, может даже расстановка приоритетов? Меня больше интересует PhpStorm, но другим будет интересно узнать про их IDE.

P.S.
 Есть конечно спец-метка в комментах `TODO`, но хотелось бы представлять костыли и `TODO` отдельно друг от друга, всё таки они сильно разные по сути. Поэтому некоторые договариваются о специальных комментах вроде:

```
/* TRASHCODE {why below code is bad} */
...
/* TRASHCODE end*/
```

Потом по коду выискать просто, но помощи IDE в обозрении костылей в таком случае нет.

Comment: Ctrl+A, Del? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> хотелось бы представлять костыли и TODO отдельно друг от друга

Во-первых, все приличные IDE кроме `TODO` понимают "из коробки" ещё и `FIXME`.

> но помощи IDE в обозрении костылей в таком случае нет

Во-вторых, все приличные IDE :) умеют добавлять пользовательские таск-теги.

**PhpStorm** (и любые другие джетбрейновские):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Eclipse** (можно кастомизировать даже для каждого языка/проекта):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> для FIXME и TODO - можно обозначать конец? То есть выделить с помощью комментов блок.

Насколько понимаю - нет, везде отслеживается только одна строка с ключевым словом. Максимум что можно - кликнуть по ней в соответствующей закладке и перейти к этому месту в исходнике.

**CLion**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В закладке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Eclipse**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В закладке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не подскажешь, для FIXME и TODO - можно обозначать конец? То есть выделить с помощью комментов блок.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, добавил в ответ.

Comment: @PinkTux дату не исползуете в теге? И если вы не один разработчик, то и имя: TODO (Вася-1212172221), штамп времини потом используется как ID фикса

Answer (score 1):

> Ахахах...Нет ничего более **постоянного**, чем **временное** решение

Если Вы не можете писать лаконичный и гибкий код для определенной задачи, то у вас проблемы с проектированием архитектуры и стоит подтянуть свои скилы, такие проблемы у начинающих разработчиков из-за недостатка опыта. Помните, что один костыль требует нагромождения новых костылей, расширение системы и ее функционала, а также внесение изменений будет затруднено.

Вы немного неправы про отсутствие костыля в английском языке, оно часто называется **[kludge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge)** or [**workaround**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround)

Куски кода которые требуется исправить часто отмечают с помощью **FIXME**, которую поддерживают многие редакторы и PHPSTORM тоже, оно отмечается в TODO. FIXME ставиться непосредственно перед проблемным участно и может содержать описание в каких строках код содержит проблемы и что за проблемы, которые нужно исправить, ограничителя нет.

```
FIXME: строки 38-120 имеют низкую абстракцию.
```

### Опыт

Могу сказать, что я и коллеги, мы **редко помечаем** костыли. Часто они сразу переписываются без пометок в момент новой задачи или поиска ошибки (класс уже несколько раз стрельнул, даже после исправления), потому что все эти пометки с недостатком времени превращаются в **постоянные**. Переписываются естественно костыли **без фанатизма**, в целях экономии средств бизнеса на дальнейшую разработку и поддержку продукта.

Если в команде поддерживается стремление к высокому уровню абстракции и соблюдению правил количества строк в классе, рефакторинг какого-то кривого кода **не занимает много времени**, но если достался в наследство, то нужно определять **уровень рефакторинга** в зависимости от предоставленного времени на задачу.

P.S Избегайте лишних парадигм: **костылирование**, **инкостыляция** и **поликостылизм**, пишите красивый код приложив к нему хотя бы минутку проектирования.

Comment: IMHO, TODO и FIXME - совершенно нормальное явление при "практике частых коммитов". В пуш их, конечно, попадать должно как можно меньше, но в процессе работы их бывает немало, что в этом плохого? Это не более чем ещё один инструмент для навигации по "сырому" исходнику.

Comment: >Если Вы не можете писать лаконичный и гибкий код для определенной задачи, то у вас проблемы с проектированием архитектуры и стоит подтянуть свои скилы, такие проблемы у начинающих разработчиков из-за недостатка опыта.

Comment: @Firepro ну плохое начало ответа, что за гордливость, а) Кто не понимает почему необходимы костыли - тот не бывал на передовой. Потому что заказчику что-то припёрло, потому что денег на всех не хватает, потому что ПМ-а нет в принципе, потому что проект горит, и что-то надо срочно делать, потому что кто-то хочет заработать.

Comment: @Firepro  и кстати не ходит у них в обиходе kludge , по крайней мере знакомые иностранцы недоумевали, что я под этим имею в виду. Насчёт workaround не слышал.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр более часто используют workaround (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%91%D0%BC) и оно часто встречается в статьях. Я могу понять костыль от недостатка времени или обхода временного бага в сторонней библиотеке, или когда весь проект уже в костылях, и писать адекватное решение уже нет смысла(дорого), но все остальное связано с недостатком опыта. Хотя даже когда времени мало (не экстремально мало и это фатальный баг), все-таки стоит основываться на уже реализованных решениях и это позволит сократить костыльность.

Comment: @Firepro так а времени всегда недостаток - много времени только в проектах for fun , или для обучения, или там где это время очень щедро оплачивают. Заказчики всегда заинтересованы в получении своей задачи как можно быстрее, иногда доходит до маразма. А когда просто не знаешь, как написать без костыля, или не можешь встроить готовое решение, или не можешь сделать костыль хорошим кодом - очевидно это недостаток опыта.

Comment: "_костылирование, инкостыляция и поликостылизм_" - улыбнуло :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
#region FIXME Bug text
...
#endregion
```

Javascript

```
//region FIXME Bug text
...
//endregion
```