# Возможна ли генерация шаблонов паттернов проектирования?

Tags: intellij-idea

Основная структура/логика любого паттерна - всегда одинакова, насколько я понял.
Появилась мысль - а что, если заготовки этих паттернов добавить в Postfix Correction?(Когда в IDEA вводишь fori + tab - и оно разворачивается в цикл for(), где только нужно имя переменной задать, только тут - задать имена переменных, класcов, интерфейсов и т.д).
Возможно есть уже такое решение готовое? Или какие-то альтернативы?

Answer (score 2):

нет невозможно. у разных язык программирование ест свои синтаксические лимиты. ваши шаблоны реализации не может подойти к всем языком программирование. пример, паттерн стратегия в C# в большом мере использует делегаты, но в классике используется абстрактные типы наподобие интерфейсах.эти задачи в большинства относится к Case средства проектирования информационных систем.

Answer (score -4):

Нашел способ через Live Templates, написанием собственных шаблонов.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/193714)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос? Серьезно?

Comment: Именно так. Как информация о том, что вы нашли способ решить вопрос поможет другим пользователям с таким же вопросом? Опишите подробнее ваш способ. Как им пользоваться? Пример?

Comment: Я написал, что нашел решение - и указал на него. Не такая сложная тема, в гугле уйма статей, хватит всем.
Вопрос не стоял "Как пользоваться Live Templates", и сами же правила сервиса требуют задавать вопросы, на которые можно дать однозначный ответ, а не гайды расписывать с листингами и пошаговыми фото. Для этого можно и на Хабр пойти. 
Я не прав?

Comment: ну отчего же. вот мой ответ [Как использовать маски слоев (layermask) и для чего пишут 1 << layer?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/603545/191482)  подробно расписан. или [отладка зависающего приложения VS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606980/191482) аналогично ....хотя мог написать: "вам нужно копать вот в таком-то направлении". Сейчас ваш ответ неинформативен и бесполезен

Comment: Для меня он был крайне полезен и информативен. Чем я и поделился с читающими. Туториал "Как скопировать отсюда и вставить сюда" - это уровень 3-го класса, простите. Это не разбор кода или сложного функционала - это просто Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V; Не думал что найдутся люди, которые с таким не справятся.

Comment: @eugeneek, да вроде является. Хотя всё равно сама идея в вопросе (не в ответе) слишком странная, чтобы работать.

Comment: может, стоит добавить к ответу снимки экрана... посмотрите вот этот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573403/183314